# For what function f does df.apply(f) convert all negative values to zero?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that `df` is a Pandas dataframe consisting entirely of floating-point numbers.

---

I know that

```
df[df < 0] = 0
```

replaces all negative values in `df` with zeros, but I'm asking something different.  I want to know what function `f` I must use in the expression

```
df.apply(f)
```

...such that the resulting dataframe has zeroes at the location where `df` has negative numbers.

---

FWIW, the following failed with an error:

```
df.apply(lambda x: max(x, 0))
```

...and the following produced the wrong result:

```
df.apply(lambda x: numpy.max(x, 0))
```

---

More generally, how does one apply a *non-vectorized*, scalar-returning function to *every* cell of a dataframe *A*, thereby producing a new dataframe with the same shape as *A*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That requires [applymap](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), not apply:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2))

df
Out: 
          0         1
0  1.157994 -0.729533
1 -1.062847  1.119744
2 -0.424534 -0.058468
3  0.465355 -0.838637

df.applymap(lambda x: max(x, 0))

Out: 
          0         1
0  1.157994  0.000000
1  0.000000  1.119744
2  0.000000  0.000000
3  0.465355  0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

(**NB:** I accepted ayhan answer because I find it ultimately more generally useful, but the answer below is, strictly speaking, closer to what I actually asked for.)

---

```
import numpy as np

lambda x: np.maximum(x, 0)
```

**NB:** `np.maximum` should not be confused with `np.max`!

E.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2))

df
#           0         1
# 0  0.065962 -0.146952
# 1  0.248722  0.529046
# 2 -1.027380  0.632114
# 3  0.928840 -0.188312

df.apply(lambda x: np.maximum(x, 0))
#           0         1
# 0  0.065962  0.000000
# 1  0.248722  0.529046
# 2  0.000000  0.632114
# 3  0.928840  0.000000
```